# How to make an SKNode continue in the same direction after finishing following a path

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

In my project I have an SKNode following a CGPathRef made with touchesMoved.  What I want to have happen is once it reaches the end of the CGPathRef, it follows in the same direction that it ended in.  I am using the SKAction followPath and tried to implement this by adding a line from the last point on the path (touchesEnded) all the way to the end of the scene using some previous points and a unit vector however this was not only complicated but also very inconsistent.  Is there another method I can use to make it just continue on its path after it finishes the CGPath?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest storing your node's CGVector (dx, dy) which represents the direction of movement for your node. For example, if the last moving vector was 15,15 that translates to your node having moved up and to the right. You can use this value to continue moving. If the values are too low or too high, you can add a min/max filter.